# How can we extract all sub module from parent module?

Tags: java, maven, svn, gwt

I checkout a project from `SVN` which contain many sub module.
In my collogue system these all module are showing like a separate module. some one else did this configuration

but in my system its showing a single module like..

how can I does same thing ..

this project contain so many technologies like `Maven` `Gwt` `Java`

please help me how this all are working I have no idea of this configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ide is eclipse with maven plugin. you can navigate to annual-web in the project you have checked out. Right click on annual-web-> select import->type maven in filter-> click on existing maven projects-> select the pom->click finish